Iterator for nested loops unrolling in C++
Very often I have nested loops at least two-level depth where elements from the same container interact which each other. Imagine interaction of particles in physics.
This leads to two cases of the code:
struct vec2f {
    float x, y;
};

void each_to_each(std::vector<vec2f>& vec)
{
    std::for_each(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), [&]([[maybe_unused]] const auto& pos1) {
        const auto it = std::begin(vec) + (&pos1 - std::data(vec));
        std::for_each(it + 1, std::end(vec), [&]([[maybe_unused]] const auto& pos2) {
            // Some actions with pos1 and pos2 (like particles interaction)
        });
    });
}

void each_to_each_symmetrical(std::vector<vec2f>& vec)
{
    std::for_each(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), [&]([[maybe_unused]] const auto& pos1) {
        std::for_each(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), [&]([[maybe_unused]] const auto& pos2) {
            if (&pos1 == &pos2) {
                return;
            }

            // Some actions with pos1 and pos2 (like particles interaction)
        });
    });
}

Which I don’t like for too verbose syntax, difficulties to exit from inner loop, nested brackets, etc.
So, typical way to avoid it is to put these loops into a wrapper:
template<typename Functor>
void each_to_each_with_functor(std::vector<vec2f>& vec, Functor fn)
{
    std::for_each(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), [&](const auto& pos1) {
        const auto it = std::begin(vec) + (&pos1 - std::data(vec));
        std::for_each(it + 1, std::end(vec), [&](const auto& pos2) {
            fn(pos1, pos2);
            });
        });
}

void foo([[maybe_unused]]const vec2f& pos1, [[maybe_unused]] const vec2f& pos2) {
    // Some actions with pos1 and pos2 (like particles interaction)
}

Which works fine, but keeps the issue with exit from the nested loop and additionally brings issue with passing the context (local variables defined before the loop) into the function; when there are many of them, this is too verbose. Sometimes, performance could be an issue as well.
My idea is to implement a kind of iterator and wrapper to it which will incapsulate processing of nested loops (with pair of iterators) and which will be able to work in single-level loop for the developer.
So the usage should be like:
    std::vector<vec2f> vec;
    NestedLoopIterator loop = NestedLoopIterator(vec.begin(),vec.end());

    std::for_each(loop.begin(), loop.end(), [&](const auto& its) {
        const vec2f& pos1 = its.it1;
        const vec2f& pos2 = its.it2;

        // Some actions with pos1 and pos2 (like particles interaction)
    });

It could define traversing strategies (like two shown at the beginning of the question), handle multithreading, could be configurable for nesting levels, etc.
Just to avoid reinventing the wheel, is there known implementation of such iterator?
If not and you see significant drawbacks of such solution and flaws in the proposed draft of design, please share your input. I am still in two minds if this is a good idea and that benefits would overweight the introduced complexity.
Here is the demo without NestedLoopIterator implementation so far.

each_to_each_with_functor could take a lambda, thus could capture anything declared before. so I'm not convinced that creating an iterator would be more handy. For the early return from the loop, you could have your 'functor' to return a boolean that indicate to continue or stop.

Have you explored the ranges library (range-v3 github version, or standard that made it to C++20)? views::cartesian_product may be of particular interest of you as it looks similar to your NestedLoopIterator. I had some bad experience with it few years ago (iterators could not be copied independently) but this may have changed a lot since then.

@OznOg I am in favor of using functors too. I just use strong enum for functor returning, e.g. Loop::Continue and Loop::Break for the sake of readability (what that 'return true' actually means?). You could easily add Loop::BreakOuther and Loop::BreakInner in the context of nested loops.

@CygnusX1 why not. Worth to notice that if you want to parallelise the code (use openMP for example) early return in loop is not possible.

Did you know that if you know the size of the arrays at compile time you can combine std::array + std::apply to do loop unrolling :  see https://godbolt.org/z/E466bzcqW

Maybe related to this post

@OznOg, capturing with lambda is a good catch, thank you. I somehow missed this while using this technique in many other different places. Hope this would be optimization-friendly.

@CygnusX1, thank you, it seems (with the research provided already after your post by Bohdan Lakatosh in his answer below) to be very close approach, although I am not sure it would be scalable enough to support many level of nesting and multithreading (which is not supported yet in ranges). Anyway, the approach itself could be helpful to study.

@PepijnKramer, I didn't, but I still not sure it is related. Most likely the confusion is caused by my use of term "unrolling" which couldn't be the best fit here. I don't want to unroll the loop in a classical meaning (remove the loop and replace with a sequence of operators), I want to collapse many nested loops in one (should I rename the question with this term)? Or you mean that the same approach could help here?

@edrezen, I am not sure. That post still wants to pass all the elements once linearly, while I need each-to-each pass which require O^n interactions (with n=2 in the simplest case). If you see that I miss a way to use the technique from that post here, please, pinpoint.

If you can use c++23 (or c++20 with a little adaptation), you could use coroutines and generators.
Like you can define generators in Python, it becomes possible in c++ to write the logic of your iterations the way you want (like you did in each_to_each for instance) and once you have the item you want to be used, you can make it available with co_yield.
For the end user, one has just to use the function as a generator:
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <generator> 

template<typename T, typename U=T::value_type>
auto each_to_each (T& vec) -> std::generator<std::pair<U,U>>
{
    for (auto it1=std::begin(vec); it1 != std::end(vec); ++it1)
    {
        auto it = std::begin(vec) + std::distance(std::begin(vec), it1) + 1;
        
        for (auto it2=it; it2 != std::end(vec); ++it2)
        {
            co_yield std::make_pair (*it1,*it2); 
        }
    }
}


int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3, 4};

    for (auto item : each_to_each(vec))
    {
        std::cout << item.first << " " << item.second << "\n"; 
    }
       
    return 0;
}


Demo
This is somehow a lazy way to get for-range loops for free when writing a full fledged iterator seems tedious.

Update: I simplified and corrected the example (ie. +1 when defining it) and mostly remove const for the input parameter (temporary objects not possible here).

Update: Here is an interesting post about coroutines and performance.

Thank you so much! I like the solution. What would you recommend for processing early exits (like mentioned in the comments to the original question - continue/break) in case I want to process them in client's loop (which in main function in your example)?

Actually, I would say that a generator should always return the same kind of objects and doesn't have to be verbose about the reason why it breaks at some point in one of the inner loops. In case you need to provide extra information, you could rely on a tuple (instead of a simple pair) that could include some extra information. Note also that writing generators like this makes it easy to break at one level or another when  some condition occurs; it just continues with the outer loop and will proceed with the remaining co_yield to come.

You can implement these types of iterations using range-v3 library.
However I do not think that these ranges will show the best performance possible. I am not an expert in range library, just a guts feeling, I get from looking at the code and seeing all those extra stuff being created.
Here is a naive implementation of your iterations using range-v3 library.
Note that each_to_each_symmetrical iteration does not need to have 2 loops at all (just based on your example above, correct me if I am wrong), thus no ranges in that example. But if you insist of having some sort of "double iteration" there, range-v3 library has implementation of ranges::views::zip.
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

int main() {
    std::cout << "each_to_each case\n";

    std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3, 4};
    auto rng = ranges::views::cartesian_product(ranges::views::enumerate(vec),
                                                ranges::views::enumerate(vec)) |
               ranges::views::filter([](const auto& entry) {
                   const auto& [l, r] = entry;
                   return l.first < r.first;
               }) |
               ranges::views::transform(
                   [](const auto& entry) -> std::pair<const int&, const int&> {
                       const auto& [l, r] = entry;
                       return {l.second, r.second};
                   });

    std::ranges::for_each(
        rng, [](const std::pair<const int&, const int&> entry) {
            std::cout << "(" << entry.first << " ; " << entry.second << ")\n";
        });

    // Output:
    // (1 ; 2)
    // (1 ; 3)
    // (1 ; 4)
    // (2 ; 3)
    // (2 ; 4)
    // (3 ; 4)

    std::cout << "each_to_each_symmetrical case\n";
    std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const auto& el) {
        std::cout << "(" << el << " ; " << el << ")\n";
    });

    // Output:
    // (1 ; 1)
    // (2 ; 2)
    // (3 ; 3)
    // (4 ; 4)

    return 0;
}

You can implement the same thing using different kind of views. You can read more about views here

UPDATE
I studied range-v3 documentation from the link above a bit more and it turns out that the library has a framework to implement your own views. Pretty handy! Specifically for this case.
Here is some quick implementation for each_to_each view:
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

class each_to_each_view : public ranges::view_facade<each_to_each_view> {
    friend ranges::range_access;

   public:
    explicit each_to_each_view(std::span<const int> data) : data_{data} {}

   private:
    std::pair<int, int> read() const { return {data_[lc_], data_[rc_]}; }
    bool equal(ranges::default_sentinel_t) const {
        return data_.empty() || lc_ >= data_.size() - 1;
    }
    void next() {
        ++rc_;
        if (rc_ >= data_.size()) {
            ++lc_;
            rc_ = lc_ + 1;
        }
    }

    std::span<const int> data_;
    std::size_t lc_{0};
    std::size_t rc_{1};
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "each_to_each case\n";

    std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3, 4};

    auto rng = each_to_each_view(vec);

    std::ranges::for_each(
        rng, [](const std::pair<const int&, const int&> entry) {
            std::cout << "(" << entry.first << " ; " << entry.second << ")\n";
        });

    // Output:
    // (1 ; 2)
    // (1 ; 3)
    // (1 ; 4)
    // (2 ; 3)
    // (2 ; 4)
    // (3 ; 4)
    return 0;
}

This one creates much less redundant objects during iteration, so I would expect that this example will be more performant then the previous one. However I did not measure.

Thank you so much for your help and research here, it helps a lot! I will get back with some additional questions after playing with the code. Meanwhile, I am not sure I got you statement "Note that each_to_each_symmetrical iteration does not need to have 2 loops at all (just based on your example above, correct me if I am wrong), thus no ranges in that example.". Could you please comment why in my case the nested loop is not required here while I need each-to-each interaction, excluding self-interaction?

Ah, I see, sorry I misunderstood your code. I thought that you search the element with the same address in the inner loop, in your example, when you were explicitly skipping it. Yes, then for that case my solution above is not correct. But you still can implement it as a custom view

So, to avoid misguiding other people I would remove "accept" mark so far. Would you like to update your answer to make it fit? In no way I would like to lose this answer, anyway, it is really helpful.
